# How do you turn red notification badges off for individual apps?

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, 7.0-nougat, huawei

Apologies if this is the wrong stack site to post this question on. I wasn't sure which was best. I have a Huawei p10 phone (on Android 7.0 Nougat). I have searched and searched on-line but there doesn't appear to be any coherent information on how to solve this problem.

I am in a lot of groups on WhatsApp that have a lot of people in them. For this reason, I would like the red icon that appears on the app as a number of notifications to be switched off, as it isn't really telling me anything (except that there are absolutely loads of messages!). I only want it turned off for this app.

I have tried turning the allow notifications switch under 'Settings > Notifications and Status Bar > Notifications Management > WhatsApp' to off, however it doesn't appear to have done anything! ANy help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Doesnt appear to be a way to switch them off inside the whatsapp application settings either.

Comment: The red icon with number is the notification count for each app. And, you're may be using your stock launcher, and I don't think that you can customize on stock launcher. Try to use another launcher such as nova launcher, in which you can change it to dots or numbers or icons.

Comment: I only have Huawei Home listed as a launcher. How do I add another launcher? Should I just search for Nova launcher in the play store and download it?

Comment: yes. before that, check settings-> Apps->whatsapp, then in notifications, try settings given there. (Ex: Blockall). And, check whether it counts again. N.B. It will block all notifications from whatsapp.